# what is core?

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i am using opencv with ros environmnt and after many trials ,, a file named core is created !! and is of size 185 MB and i am wondering what is the need of this ??? its just got generated automatically from the code which have opencv, librealsense etc headers ,..

any one ??

thanks all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260977/what-is-core-!!/) by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is probably a *core dump*, which is a file that gets generated when your program(s) run into a `SEGFAULT` (ie: crash).

See [wikipedia/coredump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) for some background.

Note that this is not really ROS related, but more a generic Linux/programming question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3